# API design: data in response vs another method

Tags: javascript, api, rest

What is the best practice for returning data in a response, where the request made to the API then relies on various async calls to get the data?

Approach 1
e.g.

- Make request
- Function then has to get/process a/b/c/d async things
- Return data

One approach I had was waiting and returning the data in `res.data(..` (express) however, this seems bad practice - the response could take a while e.g. 5-10 seconds

Approach 2:
A second approach would be

- Make request
- Return 200 ok response quickly
- Function then has to get/process a/b/c/d async things
- POST this data out to another endpoint of the application, to be received and displayed

---

Is method 2 the best way or am I missing another common pattern used for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, there are three ways to handle potential long response times, two of which you've already captured:

1. Wait for a response, like you mentioned this could take some time and depending on your use case (ex. an actual human is waiting) may not be the best experience
2. Send back a 200OK indicating that the server received the request and is working on it, then the client will make a GET request to the server to ask for an update. (aka the data is "pulled" from the server)
3. Send back a 200OK, have the client configure a notification endpoint, the server will notify the client when the response has been determined. (aka have the data get "pushed" from the server)

There are benefits to all three and the fun part of API design is the right answer depends on your situation.

For most applications I work on, I tend to recommend the third option where the response is pushed from the server to the client. This is because:

- When you receive a notification you're waiting the perfect amount of time, every time. When you "pull" the response from the server you may either send your GET request too soon and the server isn't ready or wait longer than you have to to send the GET request.
- You can separate the logic between sending a request to the server and handling the response and triggering other events to happen. I personally find this separation useful when the request is asynchronous anyway

A consequence of a notification handler is that it does increase the complexity of your software which may not be what you need for your particular project.

Comment: Thanks for the scenarios - I had not thought about scenario 2, but I can see why that could be useful in cases. Appreciate the insight!